# Срез списка по установленному шаблону

Tags: python

Возможно ли сделать срез списка по установленному шаблону? Необходимо шаговое извлечение, например, одного или другого кол-ва элементов с пропуском одного или другого кол-ва элементов.
Пример:

```
list_a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
Желаемый результат: [1, 2, 5, 6, 9, 10]
```

Comment: В данном случае генератором списка можно воспользоваться

Comment: Как шаблон выглядит-то? А то "одного или другого кол-ва элементов с пропуском одного или другого кол-ва элементов" выглядит как-то странновато.

Answer (score 2):

```
list_a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
pat = [1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1]

y=[x for i,x in enumerate(list_a) if pat[i]!=0]
print(y)
```

Результат:

```
[1, 2, 5, 6, 9, 10]
```

И никаких дополнительных библиотек.

А вот если бы массив был бы очень большой - тогда попробовал бы ускориться с помощью numpy:

```
import numpy as np
list_n=np.array(list_a)
pat_n=np.array(pat,dtype=bool)
print(list_n[pat_n])
```

Comment: а если в `list_a` будет ноль?

Comment: @Danis -  Спасибо, исправил.

Comment: вместо `pat[i] != 0` можно написать просто `pat[i]`. Также можно использовать `zip`: `[x for x, y in zip(list_a, pat) if y]`

Comment: Спасибо.........

Comment: @Kerry The King - вам, как новичку на сайте подскажу: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 1):

можно с помощью библиотеки itertools:

```
from itertools import compress

list_a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
pat = [1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1] # шаблон

list(compress(list_a, pat)) # [1, 2, 5, 6, 9, 10]
```

Comment: Спасибо.........